# Get prime numbers and its reverse as primes

Tags: java, loops, math, primes

I'm trying to get number lets called it `reversedPrime` reversed prime is a number that can be a prime and its reverse is prime to, e.g `17` is prime it's reverse `71` is prime too so its `reversedPrime`, I have wrote a complete example:

```
 public static void printReversedPrime() {
    int NUMBER_OF_REQUiRED = 100;
    int NUMBERS_PER_LINE = 10;
    int count = 0, number = 1;

    while (count < NUMBER_OF_REQUiRED) {
        if (isReversedPrime(number)) {
            count++;
            if (count % NUMBERS_PER_LINE == 0)
                System.out.println(number);
            else
                System.out.print(number + " ");
        }


        number++;
    }
}

private static boolean isReversedPrime(int number) {
    return isPrime(number) && nonPalindromicIsPrime(number);
}

private static boolean nonPalindromicIsPrime(int number) {
    int digit;
    int reserved = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= number ; i++) {
        digit = number % 10;
        reserved = (reserved * 10) + digit;
        number = number / 10;
       // System.out.print(reserved);
    }



    return isPrime(reserved);
}

private static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= number / 2 ; divisor++) {
        if (number % divisor == 0){ // if true number is not prime
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I execute the program but I have a strange out-put, I should have some thing like:

`13 17 31 37 71 73 79 97 107 113
149 157 167 179 199 311 337 347 359 389`

but i'm getting:

`11 22 33 55 77 11111 33113 77117 99133299211331 77337
11433477433599511677611771 33773 99779 33899877997 110330770990331113 772113131 773137 993994115775336776337173 997179 118119191`

What did I do wrong?

Maybe someone point me?

Comment: Is the print statement in the method `nonPalindromicIsPrime` intended? I guess your output is affected by it

Comment: You're reducing number in nonPalindromicIsPrime, while keeping the for condition as I<=number. You should use a while loop instead

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that, i forgot to delete that print statement. @Assafs am was using while loop indeed but changed it in order to get right result

Comment: I think it's not important to leav my question any more, do i have to delete it ?

Comment: Don't you want to wait for an answer?

Comment: @Assafs it's already solved.

Comment: Idea: (1) if you are doing 7xyz3 you (first digit >= lastdigit) you already know whether 3zyx7 is a prime. (2) Much much faster: skip numbers that start with 2, 4, 5, 6, 8; like 8000..8999. For that divide by the last power of 10: 1000. (3) nonPalindromicIsPrime should be named palindromeIsPrime

Answer (score 1):

In case you are interested in a `functional` solution, using `streams` from java 8:

```
IntStream.iterate(2, value -> value + 1)
            .boxed()
            .map(integer -> new BigInteger(Integer.toString(integer)))
            .filter(bigInteger ->
                bigInteger.isProbablePrime(10) &&
                        new BigInteger(new StringBuilder(bigInteger.toString()).reverse().toString()).isProbablePrime(10))
            .limit(NUMBER_OF_REQUiRED)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: So i don't to make my hand dirty with code yet, just a simple functions do it for me. thnx

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.primes.Primes;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int number=11; number<11111; number++) {
            if(Primes.isPrime(number) == false) {
                continue;
            }

            String string = new StringBuilder("" + number).reverse().toString();

            if(Primes.isPrime(Integer.valueOf(string)) == false) {
                continue;
            }

            System.out.println(number);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the range [11..11111] any number starting with the digit 2, 4, 5, 6 or 8 is not going to be a prime when reversed, allowing for 20, 50, 200, 500 etc. as exceptions.  There is no need to test those numbers.  Large parts of your loop can be skipped, much of 4001 to 6999 for instance.